# Entity Framework object not persisting/saving to database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, mdf

I have entity model created in Visual Studio 2010.This is part of my code:

```
Database1Entities1 de = new Database1Entities1();
UserInfo ui = new UserInfo();
ui.Name = "xxx";
ui.Username = "xxx";
ui.Password = "xxx";
de.UserInfoes.AddObject(ui);
```

It executes without problems, but new data is no added in the table.
Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: You would need to call de.SaveChanges(); if this is Entity Framework to persist the changes back to the database.

Comment: @mservidio: You should probably make that an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to call

```
de.SaveChanges();
```

if this is Entity Framework to persist the changes back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the save method on de after you've added the object.